# SQL Application Debugging from VS2010 and SQL Server 2008 - unable to hit breakpoint in stored proc

Tags: sql-server, debugging

I know there are other questions here concerning this same issue, but I none of the suggestions on any of the questions are helping.

I'm trying to debug a stored procedure, to step into its code from a VB.Net application.

I can step into the stored procedure using Server Explorer in VS 2010. I can't, however, go from code in my .Net app into the stored procedure. I have breakpoints both in my .net code, at the line reading "ExecuteNonQuery()" and one in my stored procedure. When I run the app in debug mode, my break point in the stored proc reads "this breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." When my breakpoint is hit in the .Net code, execution goes from the ExecuteNonQuery line straight to the next line of .Net code - no hitting of my breakpoint in the stored proc.

I have SQL debugging enabled for the .Net project. I have "Enable SQL/CLR debugging" enabled for the data connection to my database in Server explorer. My debugger is attached to Managed (4.0), Native and T-SQL processes (confirmed via the Attach to Process dialog in the debug menu).

The sql server instance and the VS instance are both on my local machine, and I am an administrator of it. I am running the app from Cassini and it is running under my own account. I am running VS2010 V 10.0.40219.1 sp1 Rel and SQL Server 2008 with SP 2 installed on a 64 bit Win2k8 machine.

Help, please - anyone! I have wasted 2 days on this!

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to step into the sp? I have always had trouble doing this from Visual Studio especially in 2010. I would just recommend running a trace on your DB and capturing the sp call and then  debugging that. That way you know exactly what parameters are being passed into the SP.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I thought I'd provide the following work-a-round solution which will allow you to debug the Stored Proc and may be of value to someone else who comes to this question.  Hopefully you'll find the steps of value!

Suggested steps:

1. **Run SQL Server Profiler** (e.g. From within *SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)* - select the menu item **Tools** -> **SQL Server Profiler**).
2. With SQL Server Profiler **connect** to your local SQL Server instance.
3. Click the **Run** button on the *Trace Properties* window.
4. *NOTE: You should note that SQL Server Profiler will now be monitoring activity on your local SQL Server instance (e.g. Stored Proc executions etc.).*
5. As before put a **break-point** set on the **ExecuteNonQuery()** statement.
6. **Run your .Net code** which should hit the break-point noted above.
7. Before executing the break-point ExecuteNonQuery() statement go back to **SQL Server Profiler** and *clear the trace* (using **CTRL+Shift+Del** or clicking on the **Clear Trace Window** button.
8. Now within VS **execute / step-over** the **ExecuteNonQuery()** statement.
9. *Within **SQL Server Profiler** note that a trace of the Stored Proc is now captured (along with any params).*
10. Within **SQL Server Profiler** simply **copy the trace results** (i.e. Stored Proc with params).
11. **Open a new query window** within **SSMS**.
12. Ensure to **connect** to your *local instance Database* and *start debugging* by **Alt+F5** or from the menu **Debug -> Start Debugging**.

You should now hopefully be able to debug your Stored Proc as desired!